# Get last exception in pdb

Tags: python, exception, python-2.7, pdb

Is there a way to examine the last exception when in pdb/before entering pdb? (Using python 2.7.5).

*Immediately* (yes, I enter no other commands at all) after an exception being raised in my code, I do `sys.exc_info()`; this just results in `(None, None, None)`. At this point, I can do `pdb.pm()`, and pdb starts at the point that the exception is raised.

I'd like to be able to examine this exception object (it is not stored in a variable before being raised).

There is nothing obviously helpful in http://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html or http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html

Edit: I know about `set_trace`. I'd like to examine the exception before I modify the code.

Comment: [Get reference to the current exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20797923/get-reference-to-the-current-exception) has an answer that works for my use case: getting the last thrown exception when stepping through with pdb.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [`sys.last_value`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.last_value):

```
>>> no_such_var
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'no_such_var' is not defined
>>> import sys
>>> sys.last_value
NameError("name 'no_such_var' is not defined",)
>>> sys.last_value.args
("name 'no_such_var' is not defined",)
```

---

```
>>> no_such_var
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'no_such_var' is not defined
>>> import pdb, sys
>>> pdb.set_trace()
--Return--
> <stdin>(1)<module>()->None
(Pdb) sys.last_value
NameError("name 'no_such_var' is not defined",)
```

NOTE: This solution is not perfect. The value is set when an exception is not handled and the interpreter prints an error message and a stack traceback. For example, if the exception is caught using `try .. except ..`, `sys.last_value` is not set.

Comment: I get: `*** AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'last_value'`

Comment: @claymation, That attribute is not set if there was no exception. Execute a statement that causes an exception. For example: `1/0`

Comment: @falsetru `-> print 1 / 0`, `(Pdb) n`, `ZeroDivisionError: 'integer division or modulo by zero'`, `(Pdb) import sys`, `(Pdb) print sys.last_value`, `*** AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'last_value'` - it does not exist (python 2.6)

Comment: Per the documentation, that value is only set if the exception was fatal.

Comment: @zneak, Could you share the documentation url?

Comment: @falsetru, you literally posted it yourself: http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.last_value

Comment: @zneak, But, there's no mentation about `fatal`.

Comment: @falsetru, what is your interpretation of "These three variables are not always defined; they are set when an exception is **not handled** and the interpreter prints an error message and a stack traceback"?

Comment: @zneak, Ah, sorry for my poor English reading. Added that part in the answer. Thank you.

Comment: I appreciate the attention that this is getting; but note that it still doesn't work when tracing through pdb. Try [this](https://pastebin.com/7Ld4TZaA) and see if you can get the exception from the (pdb) prompt. Alternatively, `set_trace()` before `1/0`, hit `n` and see if you can get the exception there.

Comment: @zneak, Isn't `try .. except ...` **handing** exception ?

Comment: Yes, but what if my catch clause was like `(ZeroDivisionError, IOError, ValueError)` and I wanted to get the complete message without adding a temporary `... as exc` from pdb? As OP says: "I'd like to examine the exception before I modify the code."

Comment: @zneak, How about `import sys`, then `!sys.exc_info()`?  (didn't put this in the answer because OP already tried sys.exc_info() and got `(None, None, None)`.

Comment: @falsetru My comment was using `pdb` in a script, not the shell, similar to zneak's pastebin after your comment @-ing me

Answer (score 15):

You can retrieve the latest exception in pdb/ipdb via:

```
__exception__
```

The above is actually a tuple of the (exception, message).

Comment: "NameError: name '\_\_exception\_\_' is not defined"

Comment: same, python 3.8.x

Comment: Works for me on Google Colab. Thanks!

Comment: This worked for me when I started `pdb` first and then triggered the exception by stepping through the code. It did *not* work for me when the exception is triggered before starting `pdb` (e.g. with `pdb.post_mortem`).

Answer (score 14):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
import pdb
try:
    1/0
except Exception as err:
    pdb.set_trace()
```

---

```
% test.py
--Return--
> /home/unutbu/pybin/test.py(8)<module>()->None
-> pdb.set_trace()
(Pdb) err
ZeroDivisionError('integer division or modulo by zero',)
(Pdb) quit
```

---

If you do not want to modify the code where the exception originates, you could instead redefine `sys.excepthook`:

```
import pdb
import sys
def excepthook(type, value, traceback):
    pdb.set_trace()
sys.excepthook = excepthook

1/0
```

---

```
% test.py
--Return--
> /home/unutbu/pybin/test.py(7)excepthook()->None
-> pdb.set_trace()
(Pdb) type
<type 'exceptions.ZeroDivisionError'>
(Pdb) value
ZeroDivisionError('integer division or modulo by zero',)
(Pdb) traceback
<traceback object at 0xb774f52c>
(Pdb)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can run the script through [`pdb`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html#module-pdb) via `python -m pdb -c continue script.py`. It will enter post-mortem debugging on an uncaught exception and drop you in the pdb interface. Here you can examine `sys.exc_info()` in order to get the exception. For example:

```
$ echo "1 / 0" > script.py 
$ python -m pdb -c continue script.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  [...]
  File "/tmp/script.py", line 1, in <module>
    1 / 0
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
Uncaught exception. Entering post mortem debugging
Running 'cont' or 'step' will restart the program
> /tmp/script.py(1)<module>()
-> 1 / 0
(Pdb) !import sys
(Pdb) p sys.exc_info()
(<class 'ZeroDivisionError'>, ZeroDivisionError('division by zero'), <traceback object at 0x7f3adcf09148>)
(Pdb) interact
*interactive*
>>> import sys
>>> sys.exc_info()
(<class 'ZeroDivisionError'>, ZeroDivisionError('division by zero'), <traceback object at 0x7f3adcf09148>)
```

Comment: I only figured this out like two weeks ago myself, after using python for 12 years. It's actually a wonderful solution when available.

Comment: `(<class 'AttributeError'>, AttributeError("'Pdb' object has no attribute 'do_sys'"), <traceback object at 0x10dabf800>)` on python 3.10

Comment: ^ For the above I ended up having to use `!sys.exc_info()` which apparently executes on a different frame.

Answer (score 2):

I bumped into this post, but none of the answers did what I needed, which was to repeat all of the error information (including the traceback) that was spewed before the `pdb.pm()` step in the question. Here's what worked for me in the end:

Add the following lines to your .pdbrc file:

```
import sys
import traceback
alias rethrow traceback.print_exception(sys.last_type, sys.last_value, sys.last_traceback)
```

Now, next time you're in a pdb environment, you can just type `rethrow`, and it will repeat all the error information from before you had typed `pdb.pm()`.

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me (python 3.8)