# Get reference to the current exception

Tags: python, debugging, exception, pdb, ipdb

```
$ ./runtests.py -v tests/managers/test_customer.py:CustomerManagerTest.test_register_without_subscription --ipdb

...

test_register_without_subscription (tests.managers.test_customer.CustomerManagerTest) ... 
- TRACEBACK --------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/case.py", line 331, in run
    testMethod()
  File "*****/tests/managers/test_customer.py", line 198, in test_register_without_subscription
    1/0
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> *****/tests/managers/test_customer.py(198)test_register_without_subscription()
    197     def test_register_without_subscription(self):
--> 198         1/0
    199         ...

ipdb> import sys
ipdb> sys.exc_info()
(<type 'exceptions.AttributeError'>, AttributeError("Pdb instance has no attribute 'do_sys'",), <traceback object at 0x47eb908>)
ipdb>
```

I could not find any command in `ipdb help` that shows me current exception.

Doing `import sys; print sys.exc_info()` doesn't work.

Currently I do:

```
try:
    do_something_that_raises_an_exception()
except Exception as exc:
    import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
```

then I can work with `exc` to analyze it.

How to **easily** get a reference to the currently effective exception?

Comment: Looks like this may have already been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19211195/399704

Comment: @AaronD, the answer in your link only works in `pdb`, not `ipdb`...

Comment: @AaronD, i am getting `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'last_value'` when trying to retrieve `sys.last_value` inside an `except`: http://bugs.python.org/issue6307

Answer (score 43, accepted):

This has frustrated me too for a while.  I eventually found the answer [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20171012060156/http://www.onlamp.com/pub/a/python/2005/09/01/debugger.html?page=6), along with a good detailed explanation.

The short answer is, use the `!` magic prefix (`!sys.exc_info()`):

```
In [4]: 1/0
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ZeroDivisionError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
...
ipdb> !sys.exc_info()
(<type 'exceptions.AttributeError'>, AttributeError("'exceptions.ZeroDivisionError' object has no attribute '_render_traceback_'",), <traceback object at 0x101c55fc8>)
```

This basically tells the debugger: "guessing wouldn't be necessary. it is python code I'm typing", thus preventing it from trying to guess what you mean by "sys", a process during which some internal exception is raised, overwriting `sys.exc_info()`, which used to hold your original exception.

Comment: Thanks, this works. I was hoping there is a built-in `ipdb` command for this, otherwise I have to type: `!import sys; sys.exc_info()`

Comment: @warwaruk you can define an alias in your `.pdbrc`

Comment: Thanks! I ended up with putting `alias exc_info !import sys; sys.exc_info()` into `~/.pdbrc`

Comment: This works in both pdb & ipdb. To assign to a variable, you can use `!import sys; exc=sys.exc_info()` then you can explore it, import `traceback` and print it, etc.

Comment: Very helpful!. FYI, The link for where you got the idea no longer leads to anything relevant.