# Print the current exception in PDB interactive shell

Tags: python, exception, pdb

So I'm stepping through a script using PDB and it raises an exception, but for some reason it abbreviates the exception to the point that it is unreadable.  How do I get it to print the whole exception?  Can I get a reference to the exception?  I would think this would be a built-in command, such as "rv".

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get last exception in pdb](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19211034/get-last-exception-in-pdb)

Comment: This is not a duplicate. If you trigger an exception while in pdb those answers will not help.

Comment: If you're triggering it directly you can just use the "except Except as e" in the setup (where e is some arbitrary var you make up) and then look at e afterwards.  Not sure if this fits your use case (since it seems too obvious)

Comment: Workaround: Try copying the failing line and pasting it to pdb cli, something like:
   ex= x/0    - now u have the exception stored in ex, it is a workaround, but it works

Comment: Exceptions don't work that way.  You'd have to catch it somehow, but I'm not sure you can.

Answer (score 0):

I think, it can help:

```
try:
    **your code**
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```