# Pycharm - Break on Any Exception but ignore StopIteration and ExitGenerator

Tags: python, debugging, exception, pycharm

In Pycharm I would like to, in debug mode, stop on any exception that enters my code but ignore any exceptions that are thrown and caught by library functions.

Pycharm has an option in breakpoints called Any Exception where you can say "On Raise" and "Ignore library files" which goes a long way but it does not ignore StopIteration and ExitGenerator, which means it stops at the end of any of your generator or yield statements.

eg in the code below the generator `next((x for x in a_list))` throws an ExitGenerator exception which Pycharm stops on in debug mode, but this is actually caught and handled by libary code so I want to ignore it.

See for example this program

```py
import pandas as pd

try:
    # spurious exception
    a_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
    first_item = next((x for x in a_list))
    print(f'first item = {first_item}')

except Exception as e:
    # the program won't go here as the ExitGenerator exception is handled by the standard library
    print(f'got exception from generator : {str(e)}')

try:
    # proper exception from a library
    df = pd.DataFrame(index=[1, 2, 3], data=['a', 'b', 'c'], columns=['letters'])
    # try to access but use the wrong column name to generate an exception
    print(df['non_existent_column'])

except Exception as e:
    # the program will come here as the code tried to access a non-existent column
    print(f'got exception from pandas : {str(e)}')
```

and that produces the follow output in debug

```
Connected to pydev debugger (build 201.6668.115)
Stack: 
    <genexpr>, play.py:6
    <module>, play.py:6
first item = a
Stack: 
    <module>, play.py:17
got exception from pandas : 'non_existent_column'

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Pycharm is first catching the spurious generator exception that does not reach my code and then catching the proper pandas exception which does read my code. This is my breakpoint setting btw

[image: Pycharm Any Exception with Igoore Library Files]

Also this from a few years ago seems to be related [Break on all exceptions except if it is stop iteration or Generator Exit](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000342964-Break-on-all-exceptions-except-if-it-is-stop-iteration-or-Generator-Exit)

suggests it might have been solved but it don't know how to enable it.

Comment: You should put your update as an answer

Comment: Thanks Alex - now updated as an answer

Answer (score 15):

**Update**

I've managed to get something working based on some answers here [get-last-exception-in-pdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19211034/get-last-exception-in-pdb)

If I add this to the Pycharm condition it avoids ignores StopIteration and ExitGenerator

```py
not (isinstance(__exception__ , tuple) and len(__exception__)>=1 and __exception__[0] in [StopIteration, GeneratorExit])
```

[image: with breakpoint condition]

Comment: I am not alone!